# Excel Max function for adjacent column with "Ack" in value

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet of ports. Data goes on ports 92000 - 92499 and acknowledgements are on ports 92500 and greater. When I need to find the next available port to use I need to physically look.

Columns look like this. The number in column f, text e.g. "Ack" in column g

```
92001 Data
92500 Ack
92002 Data
92502 Ack
```

So I either need the Max function to only look at data when the port is less then 92500 or I need to be able to look at the next column and see if the data has "Ack" in it or does not.

If only I could put a where statement in there.

Comment: Are you looking for the result to be 92000 as the next available port (because it is not used), or 92003 (1 higher than the maximum)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for the the max port number in column F with criteria "Data" in column G, and then add 1 to that number, this should work for you:

```
=MAX(INDEX((G1:G4="Data")*F1:F4,))+1
```

Using the <92500 argument instead:

```
=MAX(INDEX((F1:F4<92500)*F1:F4,))+1
```

Alternately, a pivot table could perform this task quite easily:

[image: Pivot Table Solution]

Comment: your have not considered the less than 92500 argument

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a separate formula with that argument instead of looking for "Data" in column G, as well as a pivot table solution showing the max for each value in column G.